# Moving multiple files at random from dir to dir

Tags: python, random, copy

I wrote a script that will copy a single file from one dir to another.
Is there a way to select multiple? I.e. specifically 25% of the total number of files in the source dir? I have not been able to find a direct answer.

This is what I have.

```
files = os.listdir(source_dir)
index = random.randrange(0, len(files))
random_file = files[index]
shutil.copy(source_dir + random_file, output_dir)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could add the file names to a list, then have a for loop iterate through that list calling `shutil.copy(source_dir + file_in_list, output_dir)` on each elem in that list

Comment: @NathanBlaine sorry if this is dumb, but, to clarify, I would loop what I have `(number_of_files)/10` times, each time writing the file name to a `list.txt`, then use the `list.txt` in `shutil.copy`?

Comment: there is no need to write the string names to a file, you can just add them to a `list` (`myList=[]`)

Comment: @NathanBlaine oh right.. that did work, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot.  You can change the rootdir, output_dir, and percentage to whatever you want.

```
import os, shutil
from random import choice

rootdir = 'C:/images'
output_dir = 'C:/copies'
for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    if files:
        for x in range(int(len(files) *.25)):
            to_copy = choice(files)
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(subdir, to_copy), os.path.join(output_dir, to_copy))
            files.remove(to_copy)
```

Comment: I am using the suggestion by @NathanBlaine, but this did also work. Thanks!